# iOS interface builder - Vertical Sliders, Boxes, other objects?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I was using interface builder, and I clicked the objects library, and there were a bunch of objects there I hadn't seen before. This includes vertical sliders, level indicators, image wells, segmented buttons, boxes, and all sorts of things. Then I clicked media library and then went back to the object library and they were all gone. How can I use these objects and why are they hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sudden hiding is kind of mystery I am not able to explain. Anyway these objects are, most of the time preconfigured objects you can drag and drop to the views you are actually designing.
Once you put them in your views, you access their properties to change common displaying options or make connections to action methods (all you can do into Interface Builder is also possible by coding).

Answer (score 0):

UI objects are linked to the type of application you are developping.
By default, if you only launch Interface Builder you'll be able to browse all UI elements.
If you are developping an iOS application (for example), you won't be able to use them at all.